# Floquet stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Let $X_t$ be defined by the SDE

$$
dX_t = A(t, X_t)dt + dW_t
$$

where $A(t, X_t)$ is linear in $X_t$ and periodic in $t$. Assume also that the process is stable. If $A(\cdot)$ didn't have $t$ dependency, the process would be an $n$ dimensional OU process, where the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ in
$$
A(X_t) = A\cdot X_t
$$
all have negative real part. In this case it can be seen that it would reach an equilibrium (given by an invariant measure), so $X_t$ would exponentially fast approach a stationary solution. But what happens in the case of a $t$-periodic $A(t,X_t)$? Will the process be cyclostationary/what can we say about it?

Comment: I assumed the process is stable (so all the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are negative). Is that what you mean?